# Autoconf - setting compiler flags for checks

Tags: autoconf

I am trying to use `autoconf` to create a `configure` script.  However, some of the headers I want to check for require additional compiler flags (e.g. `c++11`).  I can get partly there with the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241286/autoconf-ac-check-headers-for-c11) where the relevant lines look like this in the `configure.ac` file.

```
AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11(,[mandatory])
AC_CHECK_HEADER("CL/cl2.hpp")
```

but the `std=gnu++11` flag isn't passed to the preprocessing step of `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` where I end up with the strange result where it is usable but not present:

```
checking CL/cl2.hpp usability... yes
checking CL/cl2.hpp presence... no
```

Looking in the `config.log` shows the following lines:

```
configure:3423: checking CL/cl2.hpp presence
configure:3423: g++ -E conftest.cpp
In file included from conftest.cpp:19:0
/usr/include/CL/cl2.hpp:442:2: error #error Visual studio 2013 or another C++11-supported compiler required
```

where I can clearly see that the C++ flag is not being used.  How can I have compiler flags be used in these preprocessor steps?

**EDIT**

I can manually get around this by setting the `CXXCPP` manually when running `configure` but I'd like it to run without the end user needing to know this.

```
./configure CXXCPP="g++ -E -std=gnu++11"
```

Answer (score 0):

The current solution I have come up with is to manually add:

```
CXXCPP="g++ -E -std=gnu++11"
```

directly to the `configure.ac` file.  I would be happy to hear any additional answers.

Comment: This is the same thing I do, when adding compiler flags, in my own autoconf scripts.  However, before doing so, I have autoconf macros/checks try to compile a simple program, to ensure that the compiler _does_ support flag; different compilers (and versions of compilers) may or may not support the flags, over time.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run configure like this:

```
./configure CCFLAGS="-std=c++11" CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11" CXXCPP="-std=c++11"
```